# How to filter plugin search results in wp-admin plugin search page

Tags: plugins

I want to exclude some plugins from the plugin search page so that plugins will not appear on the plugin install page in the `wp-admin` panel. I think we can filter that page using the `plugins_api` hook.

Comment: Is it to avoid admin users from installing the excluded plugins?